# How Do I push Iteration number and User number to InfluxDB from JMeter/

Tags: jmeter, time-series

I am able to push the data from Jmeter to influx using InfluxdbBackendListenerClient backend listener. I am getting the data of time, errorcount, nodeName, requestName, responseTime, testName and Threadname but I want even Iteration number and user/thread number pushed into influxdb. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is to edit the code of the InfluxdbBackendListenerClient to include those number, possibly as a variable you send through command line. 
There is no other way to integrate that data together with the results.